# how to create table if not exist in big query using command line or sql

Tags: google-bigquery

heed input or syntax how to create table if not exist in big query

tried using Mk command to create a empty table but could not find to create if table not exist

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use DDL's statamenet [CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data-definition-language#creating_a_table_only_if_the_table_doesnt_exist) for this. For example

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydataset.newtable (x INT64, y STRUCT<a ARRAY<STRING>, b BOOL>)
OPTIONS(
  expiration_timestamp=TIMESTAMP "2020-01-01 00:00:00 UTC",
  description="a table that expires in 2020",
  labels=[("org_unit", "development")]
)
```

or via command line

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false '
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydataset.newtable (x INT64, y STRUCT<a ARRAY<STRING>, b BOOL>)
 OPTIONS(
   expiration_timestamp=TIMESTAMP "2020-01-01 00:00:00 UTC",
   description="a table that expires in 2020",
   labels=[("org_unit", "development")]
 )'
```